# How to make a CollectionField appears condtionnaly in easyadmin / symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, easyadmin

Hello i'm stuck since a few days on this

How can I manage the condition to display one of my fields only if a specific value exists on the form? What I'm attempting to do is create a custom **CollectionField**, but I need to hide it or prevent adding it with configureFields if the field **isFramework** is set to True.

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            // This is the field i need to use to check if i show up the field skillsRelated 
            BooleanField::new('isFramework', 'Framework ?'),
            BooleanField::new('isEnabled', 'Activer la compétence'),
            Field::new('name', 'Nom de la compétence'),
            // Extends the field to be able to select an option on a string field
            ChoiceField::new('skillType', 'Type de compétence')->setChoices([
                'Technique' => 'technical',
                'Compétences interpersonnelle' => 'softSkills',
                'Langue' => 'language',
            ]),
            ChoiceField::new('skillLevel', 'Niveau de compétence')->setChoices([
                'None' => '',
                'Professionnel' => 'professional',
                'Courant' => 'fluent',
            ]),
            ChoiceField::new('skillField', 'Domaine de compétence')->setChoices([
                'None' => '',
                'Front-end' => 'Front-end',
                'Back-end' => 'Back-end',
                'Devops' => 'Devops',
            ]),
            // This is the field i'm trying to hide on specific condition
            CollectionField::new('skillsRelated')->setEntryType(SkillsType::class)
            ];
    }
```

Thank you for your help!